# How to add JS array to Meteor autoform entry

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using Meteor 1.1.0 and Aldeed:Autoform and I need to put values from a string array that is generated in the template's JS file into a document entry of type [String] during (or before) submit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a before: hook in Autoform.hooks with an insert: function in it, which would modify the document entries ( for this to work the parameter must be defined in the schema ). Example:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    'add-form': {
        before:{
            insert:function(doc){
                doc.fileId = '1234; // doc is the data from the form. 
                return doc; // .fileId is the element we try to modify
            }
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: Extra credit for mentioning the schema requires the field. That's what had me blocked.